# Unexpected syntax error when copying Excel VBA code from a Web site

Tags: excel, vba, syntax-error, non-ascii-characters, excel-2016

I was looking for a function to conditionally concatenate a range of cells in Excel. This function

```
Function ConcatenateIf(CriteriaRange As Range, Condition As Variant, ConcatenateRange As Range, Optional Separator As String = ",") As Variant

Dim xResult As String
On Error Resume Next
If CriteriaRange.Count <> ConcatenateRange.Count Then
    ConcatenateIf = CVErr(xlErrRef)
    Exit Function
End If
For i = 1 To CriteriaRange.Count
    If CriteriaRange.Cells(i).Value = Condition Then
        xResult = xResult & Separator & ConcatenateRange.cells(i).Value
    End If
For i = 1 To CriteriaRange.Count
Next i
If xResult <> "" Then
    xResult = VBA.Mid(xResult, VBA.Len(Separator) + 1)
End If
ConcatenateIf = xResult
Exit Function
```

from https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2723-excel-concatenate-based-on-criteria.html looked just the ticket. Comments suggested it had worked for other coders.

However, when I paste it into a VBA module in Excel2016, there are syntax errors which I can't figure out. "Exit Function" on line 7 can be resolved by deleting "Function". The call of "Exit Function" at the end doesn't register as an error but can removed as superfluous. But

```
If CriteriaRange.Cells(i).Value = Condition Then
```

is highlighted as a syntax error (and the matching "End If"). If I simply use "If true Then", the error doesn't go away, which suggests looking at the previous line

```
For i = 1 To CriteriaRange.Count
```

and I tried "For i = 1 To 8" but that doesn't fix it either. I just can't see what it wrong?

Further to the helpful responses, here is a screenshot of a direct paste into VBA

[image: shows red syntax error highlights in original code from site]

and here is a screenshot of the "dodgy" space characters as seen in Word

[image: shows spaces-as-circles with Hidden Chars on in Word]

Comment: Try changing the `On Error Resume Next` to `On Error GoTo 0` and see which line it errors on. Also check your data types of `Condition` are you sure it's passing a `String`/`Integer` and not an `Object`/`Array`?

Comment: You are having two `For i = 1 to CriteriaRange.Count`'s I suggest removing the last.

Comment: If you use the version of the code from the site you took it from, you will find that your bugs will disappear.

Comment: Pardon me, but they do not. I think you mean it worked for you when you tried it. I believe I have just found the problem - the space characters are not seen as regular spaces in my environment (which is not unusual - Excel 2016 on a regular Dell laptop). When I delete the indentation spaces and replace them using space bar, my syntax problems disappear. When I turn on Hidden Characters when viewing the text in Word, the indentation spaces appear as circles, not dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit 2

As the OP discovered, copying and pasting from the Web site gives a bunch of non-breaking spaces:

[image]

On my test case (Excel 2013, Win7), those paste in fine, and Excel doesn't barf.  However, the OP's installation (Excel 2016) can't handle them.

To change those:

- Paste the code into Word.
- Do a Find/Replace to change `^s` (nonbreaking spaces, `ChrW(160)`) to a single space ().
- Copy from Word to Excel.

### Original

All I had to do to get it to compile was:

- Comment out the second `For i=...` line
- Change `Exit Function` on the last line to `End Function`.

Haven't tested it, though.  Would you please edit your question to add the test case you are trying?

**Edit** @YowE3K beat me to it — there are some copy-and-paste errors in the code in your question.  Recopy from the site and you should be OK!

Comment: Sorry for the red herrings - I don't know how I failed to copy the code properly, clearly the changes you suggested were needed in what I posted but were not the problem I was stuck on (as neither was there in my VBA version). As I said in response to YowE3K, I have now identified the problem as being the indentation space characters. There is no "test case" as such - I just pasted the code from the website into VBA and the lines I stated were highlighted in red

Comment: If I fix the question (i.e. implement your suggestions) your answer won't make much sense anymore - what should I do? I think the eventual solution might be of use to someone, I can't believe my environment is unique (it's pretty vanilla in fact) and an error you CAN'T SEE is pretty hard to figure (at least for my sparrow brain)

Comment: @DJDave Good find!  Please don't add the working version to the question, for exactly your reasoning.  Instead, post what worked for you as an additional *answer*, and then accept it a week from now when the system will let you.  In the meantime, I added a workaround based on your discovery for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: More than happy to accept your answer - thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Testing on Excel 2010 there are 2 errors to solve:

1. You have `For i = 1 To CriteriaRange.Count` twice - you need to delete the second one. This seems it must be a typing error or something
2. The function should end with `End Function`

Working code with corrections:

```
Function ConcatenateIf(CriteriaRange As Range, Condition As Variant, ConcatenateRange As Range, Optional Separator As String = ",") As Variant

    Dim xResult As String

    On Error Resume Next

    If CriteriaRange.Count <> ConcatenateRange.Count Then
        ConcatenateIf = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = 1 To CriteriaRange.Count
        If CriteriaRange.Cells(i).Value = Condition Then
            xResult = xResult & Separator & ConcatenateRange.Cells(i).Value
        End If
    Next i

    If xResult <> "" Then
        xResult = VBA.Mid(xResult, VBA.Len(Separator) + 1)
    End If

    ConcatenateIf = xResult

End Function
```